# code crashes when sprite go to the position

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I use following code to show cloud randomly

```
- (void) cloudFly
{
  int whichcloud = (arc4random() % 2) + 1;
  CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cloud%d.png",whichcloud]];
  target.opacity = 0.3;

int minY = target.contentSize.height / 2;
int maxY = winSize.height - target.contentSize.height / 2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

target.position = ccp(winSize.width + (target.contentSize.width/2), actualY);
[self addChild:target];

int minDuration = 1.0;
int maxDuration = 3.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

// Create the actions
id actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width / 2, actualY)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cloudFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCActionSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
[_clouds addObject:target];
}

- (void)cloudFinished:(id)sender
{
  CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;
  [sprite stopAllActions];
  [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
}
```

but when the cloud flys to the position, this code will crash at line

```
- (void)cloudFinished:(id)sender
```

I use cocos2d-iphone v3.x, I try to comment/remove all codes in

```
- (void)cloudFinished:(id)sender
```

but it still crash. BWT, does ccsprite remove tag?

Comment: in the crash report what it says about the error? Another problem i assume is the cloudFinished() method gets executed before the line [_clouds addobject:target];. And here you already deleted the object target in the cloudfinished method at [self removechild:sprite cleanup:yes] but still adding the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCActionCallFunc is expecting a selector with no arguments, you should use CCActionCallBlock instead. There is an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22039128/61698).

Comment: Thanks, BTW, the tag of sprite has been removed from v3.x?

Comment: Yeah, getChildByTag is not available since version 3, if thats what you're asking about. There is getChildByName which may be of use to you.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
[ _clouds  addChild: target ];
```